’Certificate is missing required extension‘ error when using module cryptography.x509
I was using module cryptography.x509 sign certificate,when I want to verify the server cert,I got this error:Certificate is missing required extension,what extension I miss?
I'm new to this sign and certificate,so most code is copyed from x509 reference,and it is just a demo,so all I want is make the verify work
here is the code:
generate cert part
def generate_sign_sret():

    with open("csr.pem", "rb") as f:
        pem_req_data = f.read()
    server_csr = x509.load_pem_x509_csr(pem_req_data)
    with open("cert.pem", "rb") as f:
        ca_pem_req_data = f.read()
    ca_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(ca_pem_req_data)
    # 签发服务器证书
    server_cert = (
        x509.CertificateBuilder()
        # 服务器请求信息
        .subject_name(server_csr.subject)
        # 自签名证书
        .issuer_name(ca_cert.subject)
        .public_key(server_csr.public_key())
        .serial_number(x509.random_serial_number())
        .not_valid_before(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
        # 有效期一年
        .not_valid_after(datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365))
        .add_extension(
            # x509.BasicConstraints(ca=False, path_length=None),
            x509.SubjectAlternativeName([x509.DNSName("cryptography.io")]),
            # critical=True,
            critical=False,
        )
        .add_extension(
            x509.BasicConstraints(ca=False, path_length=None),
            critical=True,
        )
        .add_extension(
            x509.KeyUsage(True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True),
            critical=True,
        )
        # 使用CA的私钥签发
        .sign(key, SHA256(), default_backend())
    )
    server_cert_bytes = server_cert.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM)
    with open("server_cert.pem", "wb") as f:
        f.write(server_cert_bytes)

verify part:
def verifyCert():
    with open("cert.pem", "rb") as f:
        ca_pem_req_data = f.read()
    ca_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(ca_pem_req_data)

    with open("server_cert.pem", "rb") as f:
        server_pem_req_data = f.read()
    server_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(server_pem_req_data)

    with open(certifi.where(), "rb") as pems:
        store = Store(x509.load_pem_x509_certificates(pems.read()))
    # 创建一个受信任的store
    trust_builder = PolicyBuilder().store(store)
    verifier = trust_builder.build_server_verifier(x509.DNSName("cryptography.io"))
    try:
        verifier.verify(server_cert, [server_cert, ca_cert])
        print("Server certificate is valid.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Server certificate validation failed:", e)

thanks! --orange

There is scant documentation for that part of the cryptography package. In particular, that exception is not mentioned. Sadly, the exception message doesn't include what extension is missing. One suspicious thing I see is that you are signing the generated server cert with what is presumably the private key for cert.pem, but trying to verify it with well-known root certificates. That implies that your cert.pem was signed with the ca bit set by one of those well-known roots, which is unlikely.

Ok, that specific error is caused by the absence of the Authority Key Identifier extension in the server certificate. The cryptography.io package tries to strictly follow RFC 5280. See also https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.
